# Adding Tomcat Plugin to Flex Builder

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, flexbuilder, flex3

Is there anyway we can add the tomcat eclipse plugin to Adobe Flex Builder 3? In other words can we add all eclipse plugins to Flex Builder also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. And you don't have to download Eclipse. You can do this within Flex Builder.

What you have to do is to go to help and then go to find and install.
There you have to look for WTP (Web Tools Platform) plus WST ( Web Standard Tools) and once you select it it should say that there are some errors, but what you have to do is to select install other needed packages or something like that.

When that's done you can use Flex Builder for building java back-end and flex front-end. I also use BlazeDS since I personally think that its the best combination.

Good luck.
If you need help please ask.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the Tomcat one, but I have many Eclipse plugins I am using in FlexBuilder right now. You can Google it or look at blogs, like [this one](http://dispatchevent.org/mims/pimp-my-clipse-a-list-of-must-have-eclipse-plug-ins-for-flexflash-development/) for lists of potential plugins you might want.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Flex Builder as a plugin to an existing Eclipse Java EE install. Then you get Tomcat / Dynamic Web Project support.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already done like James Ward said you made a small mistake. Since it is so that you don't have to install Flex Builder as an plug-in in the Eclipse. The reason for that is that if you install latest Eclipse it might not support Flex Builder plug-in for some reason. But if you go the other way around you will have Flex Builder and then just install WTP and WST as plug-in for Flex Builder. In this case you will have the latest fully functional Flex Builder and Eclipse working perfectly.

But if you in any way manage to install Flex Builder the other way around you will occasionally have some bugs or issues in your Eclipse installation that you made before you installed Flex Builder in ti as a plug-in. So my advice is do it the right way first. I made that mistake and now I wish I had someone to tell me else.

Take care and good luck.