# How to install Tomcat Server on FlexBuilder

Tags: tomcat, flash-builder

I am using Flash Builder 4.5 as a standalone version. I am not using Flash Builder as a plugin to eclipse.

Now, I want to install Tomcat server on my Flash Builder.
I visited many links like :

- [Configuring an Application Server in Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Configuring_an_Application_Server_in_Eclipse.pdf)
- [Adding Tomcat Plugin to Flex Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379341/adding-tomcat-plugin-to-flex-builder)

But all of them speak about the eclipse based Flash Builder. There is no "go and install" option under my help tag.

My question is, how to install Tomcat on my standalone version of Flash Builder ? What are the steps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standalone Flash Builder 4.5 is still Eclipse, just that all the Adobe plugins are already in place. So installing additional plugins is same as with standalone Eclipse.

You can:

- go to Help / Eclipse Marketplace and search for Tomcat: I just found Mongrel plugin stating following "plugin for running tomcat (incl. ability to debugging tomcat apps or tomcat itself) from within eclipse
- go to Help / Install New Software, select appropriate site and install Tomcat plugin (you'd have to search for the site, eclipse install site might be a good candidate)

On my Mac both sit in Help menu, on Windows it should be the same.

What I've just noticed inside Preferences - if you go to Server / Runtime Environments you should see "Download additional server adapters" Link. I have just clicked on that and see a lot of adapters, unfortunately no Tomcat.

Comment: Tomasz, that was very helpful :-). I am installing it now. Hope, all goes well !

Comment: After installing, it gives me 3 icons on the top-left corner. When I click any of them, it tells `Tomcat settings should be set in Tomcat preference page`. What should I do now ?

Comment: Go to the preferences (again on Mac menu Flash Builder / Preferences), you'll find there Tomcat preferences somewhere - I don't know their exact position since I don't have Tomcat installed. Look at the edited answer also, I've found something that might be interesting for you.

Comment: Now exact Tomcat settings are up to you, I guess you would at least have to set its installation directory.

Answer (score 3):

For developing a Java/Flex application, in order to add the Apache Tomcat servers to the Flash Builder 4.5 you just have to do the followings:

Help > Install New Software > (set Work with as: Helios - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios) > Select all "Web,XML, and Java EE Development"

let it install and restart Flash Builder and then you would be able to add Tomcat servers